# how to implement this doughnut chart?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement this https://codepen.io/endymion1818/pen/ygvVgQ codeopen doughnut chart, I put the codes in my files but its js does not work. ths percentage counter works ang goes from 0 up , but the color of circle is stuck on red

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg2ty.png)

```
<style>
    .statistic {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        width: 25%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .statcircle--container {
        position: relative;
    }
    .statistic__figure {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .fig {
        font-size: 80px;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    .perc {
        font-size: 42px;
    }
    .statcircle {
        fill:none;
        stroke: #d7d7d7;
        stroke-width:25;
        stroke-miterlimit:10;
    }
</style>
<script>
    // Walkthrough of this code: https://deliciousreverie.co.uk/post/doughnut-chart-svg-animation/

    // See also: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-animated-countdown-timer-with-html-css-and-javascript/

    var values = $('.statistic');

    values.each(function () {

        var percentage = $(this).find('.figure__content .fig');
        var textcontent = percentage.text();
        var circle = $(this).find('.statcircle__animated');

        // animate text from 0 to value
        percentage.prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: textcontent
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                percentage.text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });

        function initTweens() {
            // animate circle path using GSAP DrawSVG
            TweenMax.fromTo(circle, 1.5, {
                    // animate!
                    drawSVG:"0"
                },
                {
                    drawSVG: textcontent + "%"
                }); // tween
        };
        initTweens();

    }); // each
</script>
<div class="statistic">
<div class="statcircle--container">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="enable-background:new 0 0 400 400;" xml:space="preserve">
  <circle class="statcircle statcircle__bottom" cx="200" cy="200" r="177.7"/>
        <path class="statcircle statcircle__animated" style="stroke:darkred" d="M200.6,22.3c97.9,0.3,177.1,79.7,177.1,177.7c0,98.1-79.5,177.7-177.7,177.7S22.3,298.1,22.3,200
      c0-97.8,79-177.2,176.7-177.7"/>
  </svg>
    <div class="statistic__figure">
        <div class="figure__content">
            <span class="fig">47</span>
            <span class="perc">&#37;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have inserted the codes this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's a copy paste from codepen, you've forget to import relevant 3rd party libraries used in original work. You can view them in settings -> JS -> External scripts

Add these code at the bottom of your code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js">
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/DrawSVGPlugin.min.js">
```